# Where can I find tapes of Rabbi Yitzhak Ginzburg - "Shemesh Hashem", "Mikor Mayim Chaim", "Etz Chaim","Katnus Kodem LeGadlus", "50 Shaarei Bina"?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, hearing, social-media

Where can I find the following tapes (lectures dates 20-25 years back) of Rabbi Yitzhak Ginzburg?

I'm looking for specific tapes such as:

1. "Shemesh Hashem"
2. "Mikor Mayim Chaim"
3. "Etz Chaim"
4. "Katnus Kodem LeGadlus"
5. "50 Shaarei Binah"

I would agree to pay my charity money to recover those old recordings, they are very precious to me and our community.  Those lectures cannot be found anywhere on inner.org nor on youtube nor spotify.

Note: They are pretty old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.inner.org is Rabbi Ginsburgh's official website. There are both text and audio lectures available.

Comment: I did read your question, several times. You did not mention that you had checked his site, nor did you specify that there were _specific lectures_ you were looking for, rather than specific topics.

Comment: 'Twas my pleasure. Please consider adding more information to your question so that it's clearer what you've already tried, and that you're looking not looking for generic topics.